# Gitlab codepipeline getting aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors on build

Tags: gitlab, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

wondering about getting below error, it passes the test phase but fails in build? Access right need to fixed in gitlab side apparently, but wondering how? could it be about expiration of the cached provider?

```
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
572 For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
574ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The credential chain is a series of locations AWS CLI or SDK checks to find the access credentials (Key&Secret). You have missing or invalid credential somewhere in the chain. Have a look at what are the locations SDK checks here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default

Answer (score 0):

Simply I had to add the AWS credentials as variable in gitlab settings. Since I did not had full access to gitlab I was not able to see that option ;)